# database value are not displayed

Tags: php, json, ajax

here I'm trying to fetch database values through json object but it shows only first row of my database how to show entire database .What  changes need to do in it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Output: </h3>
<div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text   replaced</div>

<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 $(function () 
 {
  $.ajax({                                      
   url: 'example.php',             
  data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                   //for example "id=5&parent=6"
  dataType: 'json',                //data format      
  success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
  {
    var uid = data[0];              //get id
    var firstname = data[1];           //get name
    var lastname = data[2];
    var email = data[3];
    var username = data[4];
    var password = data[5];
    $('#output').html("<b>uid: </b>"+uid+"<b> firstname: </b>"+firstname+"<b> lastname: </b>"+lastname+"<b> email: </b>"+email+"<b> username: </b>"+username+"<b> password: </b>"+password); 
    // $('#output').html("<b>uid: </b>"+uid+"<b> firstname: </b>"+firstname+"<b> lastname: </b>"+lastname+"<b> email: </b>"+email+"<b> username: </b>"+username+"<b> password: </b>"+password); //Set output element html

  } 
});
 }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**example.php file**

```
  <?php

 // server info
 $server = 'localhost';
 $user = 'root';
 $pass = '';
 $db = 'ocean';

 $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());


$result = mysql_query("select * from oops");        //query

$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch  result    

echo json_encode($array);



?>
```

here is mine code which gives me first row as result of my database
.But I want to show full database as result what I shoud do in this code.

Comment: is `mysql_` api still alive?

Comment: @vp_arth Deprecated since PHP 5.5.0

Comment: @ SACHIN GAJBHIYE  You are getting array of data. So, to get all the records you need to run the result in for loop.

Comment: Are php returning all records?

Comment: $array = mysql_fetch_row($result); this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch all rows and collect it into array

```
$array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: now in my example.php the first file there in uid field it gives full first row

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mysql_*`. Don't do that because it is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 use `mysqli_*` instead. You problem is that you are only fetching the very first row and not the other ones.

Use a loop for that. Something like this should suffice:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
```